# Proper response for a nameserver when no relevant query has been sent?

Tags: dns, response, nameservers

I have a very rudimentary nameserver written in Python which only makes use of `socket` and `dnslib`, mainly intended for Let's Encrypt DNS-01 challenge responses, and also a couple of A records of experimental purposes.

My question is what should the nameserver respond when a query reaches the server but it contains no relevant data which the server wants to respond to?

Should it just ignore it?

I'm asking because I've been receiving queries for `ANY leth.cc` which apparently are used for DNS amplification attacks. Before noticing this I was responding to queries with an empty answer section, now I'm not sending anything back to the address provided.

I changed from

```
data, addr = sock_dns.recvfrom(1024)
q = dnslib.DNSRecord.parse(data)
a = q.reply()
# add an answer if query is relevant
# a.add_answer(*dnslib.RR.fromZone(qname + " 30 IN TXT " + verification_code))
sock_dns.sendto(a.pack(), addr)
```

to

```
data, addr = sock_dns.recvfrom(1024)
q = dnslib.DNSRecord.parse(data)
a = q.reply()
# add an answer if query is relevant
# a.add_answer(*dnslib.RR.fromZone(qname + " 30 IN TXT " + verification_code))
if len(a.rr) > 0:
 sock_dns.sendto(a.pack(), addr)
```

Is this acceptable behavior?

---

Taking *Patrick Mevzek's* answer into consideration, I have now modified it to

```
data, addr = sock_dns.recvfrom(1024)
q = dnslib.DNSRecord.parse(data)
a = q.reply()
# add an answer if query is relevant
# a.add_answer(*dnslib.RR.fromZone(qname + " 30 IN TXT " + verification_code))
if not a.rr:
  a.header.rcode = dnslib.RCODE.REFUSED
sock_dns.sendto(a.pack(), addr)
```

While this may be the proper response for valid clients, under normal operation no query for `leth.cc` should ever be reaching the server, as there is nothing pointing to my nameserver other than the NS records which I configured in the registrars DNS online configuration interface. It's their nameservers indicating that the client should go and ask my nameserver for an answer for more specific queries which they can't answer.

But in the case of a query for `leth.cc` reaching my server, this query must be very likely originating from a very unusual source. Is it still OK to answer to those requests with a `RCODE.REFUSED`, or could the request have been spoofed in such a way, that the `addr` contains an address which should not be contacted, in order to avoid a DDOS attack of that address? After all, it's an amplification attack; is that something like a reflected DDOS attack? I don't mind MY nameserver being unter DDOS attack (that's then my business to resolve), I just don't want it to be participating in one, in case that's possible.

Also, this is not a resolving nameserver, it does not go out and query other nameservers if information can't be found. I don't see anything bad in not answering to requests to `qnames` which don't belong to this nameservers domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ignoring a query is definitively not what you want to do** (in normal operation), as the client will then try again, and switch to another nameserver at some point, so at the very least you inflict them delays, if not bad results.

Possible return codes are defined in https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters/dns-parameters.xhtml#dns-parameters-6 and mostly defined in RFC 1035.

For your case I think you have exactly what you need: **REFUSED**

It is defined as such:

> The name server refuses to
>                                   perform the specified operation for
>                                   policy reasons.  For example, a name
>                                   server may not wish to provide the
>                                   information to the particular requester,
>                                   or a name server may not wish to perform                                a particular operation (e.g., zone
>                                   transfer) for particular data.

Now, your nameserver is authoritative on some domain names. If it receives query for other ones, it should say it is not authoritative for them, which is **NXDOMAIN** or precisely RCODE 3 defined as such in RFC 1035:

> Name Error - Meaningful only for
>                                   responses from an authoritative name
>                                   server, this code signifies that the
>                                   domain name referenced in the query does
>                                   not exist.

This is a very small answer, hence you are not amplifying anything. Your server could still be hit by many such queries, and you may decide to implement rate limiting (see below). It is true that traffic being UDP your server may answer to a victim not being the true source of the query, but without amplification, and like any other nameserver in the world will do also as this is the sad fate of all UDP-based protocols.

A DDOS would be if you reply to the query with an answer being even larger (like if you tried to replied to `ANY`, even for the names you are authoritative on), as here a victim could receive a lot of traffic while the attacker would have need very little to send to you.

Also, `ANY` is more a (bad) troubleshooting tool intended for recursive nameservers (as in "give me the current state of your cache for a specific label") instead of authoritative ones. There are works currently to just deprecate it completely: https://blog.cloudflare.com/what-happened-next-the-deprecation-of-any/

Now you seem more to speak about operational problems, and DDOS attack. This is another case where even replying may be costly. Current nameservers implement a RRL mechanism, for "Response Rate Limiting", basically by reducing the rate of replies.
Have a look at this article for Bind that present the feature: https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-01000/0/A-Quick-Introduction-to-Response-Rate-Limiting.html

You may wish to implement something like that for your own nameserver if you fear it could be attacked.

Comment: Thanks, I've expanded my question based on your answer. Would you mind taking another look at it? It's about the differentiation between getting queries for my domain and domains which are not under my control/ownership.

Comment: @DanielF see update. TL;DR: return NXDOMAIN (RCODE 3) for any query on domain names for which you are not authoritative. Returning just an error code is not opening to amplification attacks. Those happen typically for recursive nameservers that reply to ANY queries.

Comment: Thanks. So, regardless of what I choose to answer: If I do answer, is it possible that my nameserver could be invoked to participate in an attack to that address in `addr`? It is originating from `data, addr = sock_dns.recvfrom(1024)`; am I guaranteed that `addr` has no IP of someone who might get targeted, but is exactly the address of the originator of the query?

Comment: See my update (we crossed exchanges). DNS uses UDP: you have **NO** guarantee that the source IP is the legitimate one. You need to live with that. The counter measures are rate limiting (not a standard, see link in reply), and DNS Cookies (see https://www.thesecuritybuddy.com/securing-dns/what-is-dns-cookies-and-how-does-it-work/)

Comment: It also helps if your upstream ISP do implement BCP38 (see http://www.bcp38.info/index.php/Main_Page)  that is basically making sure that traffic from IP adresses do indeed come from the appropriate source network (AS). Which is sadly not enough widespread (like vaccines, it helps others as well as you, so sometimes people are not willing to do it).